# ElasticBeanstalk with Amazing Linux 2 keeps timing out even with Nginx config updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I have a Flask app (WSGI) deployed to Elastic Beanstalk using the `Amazing Linux 2`. In my `/var/log/web.stdout.log`, I have:

```
Jul 13 20:47:34 ip-172-31-11-53 web: [2020-07-13 20:47:34 +0000] [1531] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1531)
Jul 13 20:47:34 ip-172-31-11-53 web: Loading generator
Jul 13 20:47:34 ip-172-31-11-53 web: cache_dir /tmp/downloads/models
Jul 13 20:47:34 ip-172-31-11-53 web: using device: cpu
Jul 13 20:47:35 ip-172-31-11-53 web: [2020-07-13 20:47:35 +0000] [1576] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1576
Jul 13 20:47:39 ip-172-31-11-53 web: Some weights of GPT2LMHeadModel were not initialized from the model checkpoint at distilgpt2 and are newly initialized: ['transformer.h.0.attn.masked_bias', 'transformer.h.1.attn.masked_bias', 'transformer.h.2.attn.masked_bias', 'transformer.h.3.attn.masked_bias', 'transformer.h.4.attn.masked_bias', 'transformer.h.5.attn.masked_bias']
Jul 13 20:47:39 ip-172-31-11-53 web: You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
Jul 13 20:48:05 ip-172-31-11-53 web: [2020-07-13 20:48:05 +0000] [3858] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:1576)
Jul 13 20:48:05 ip-172-31-11-53 web: [2020-07-13 20:48:05 +0000] [1576] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1576)
```

which indicates a 20 second timeout. However, in `.platform/hooks/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf`, I have:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s; 
proxy_read_timeout 600s; 
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s; 
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

This should give a 600 second timeout, but alas - does not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timeout.conf` should be in:

```
.platform/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf
```

as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

However you have it in `hooks` folder:

```
.platform/hooks/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf
```

This could explain why they are **not applied**. There still could be other reasons, but the wrong folder is one that is apparent at present.